# Merging two SVN directories in two different repositories

Tags: svn, merge, copy, move

I have a repository R1 with this configuration:

```
R1
|-- P11
     |--D11
     |--D12
     |--D13
     file1
     file2
     ...
```

There is another global repository R2 in which I can access directory U1

```
R2
|-- U1
     |-- P21
           |...
```

I do not have access to R2 directly, only to my directories.

I would like to copy P11 and its svn history into P21...

Is it possible to do that?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repo/R1 > R1-dumpfile

svndumpfilter include P11 < R1-dumpfile > P11-dumpfile

svnadmin load /path/to/repo/R2 --parent-dir U1/P21 < P11-dumpfile
```

( you can of course pipe the commands, but leaving them separate for the sake of understanding )

Untested, but it should get you going.

Reference : http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference! It is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You want [rsvndump](http://rsvndump.sourceforge.net/) which will dump a remote repository. Pipe it through svndumpfilter to get the directory you want, then modify its path using sed; or specify the url you want and use the --prefix option to rsvndump. Then svnload the modified dumpfile into your repository.

There's guides on the web for all of the above.